# How Vertex Weight Angle modifier actually work?

Tags: grease-pencil

At first I hoped that this modifier would allow me to easily and dynamically change the weight group data of Grease Pencil, but I still did not understand how this modifier works, and the description in the manual did not help me at all. Also, I did not find any tutorials or other descriptions about this modifier on the Internet.

Help me understand how this modifier works. Better with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I also asked this question, but it seems I found a solution and therefore I will share it.

1. Make Vertex Group in GP object and assign points into it.
2. To GP object add Vertex Weight Angle Modifier and Thickness Modifier for example.
3. In the Vertex Weight Angle Modifier choose your vertex group in Vertex Group field.
4. In the Thickness Modifier enhance Thickness Factor to 3 or above.
   Open section Influence and choose your vertex group.
5. Change or animate Angle in the Vertex Weight Angle Modifier.
   [image]